# OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision collision) isn't triggering despite collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and having problems with this method. Any help would be appreciated.

Currently, I have one box `gameObject` (customer) that falls down onto another box `gameObject` (table). The script with the`OnCollisionEnter2D` method is attached to the tableBox object and checks using tags if the customerBox has collided with it. The problem is that despite colliding, `OnCollisionEnter2D` does not seem to be getting called at all, as nothing is appearing from Debug.Log. Both boxes have `Rigidbody2D` and a `boxCollider2D`.

I have tried changing the Rigidbody2D property to dynamic and also double checking the tags are correct. It is also possible that the script for the tableBox is not running at all, which if is the case I am not sure how to fix and would appreciate suggestions.

Here is the method:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
        Debug.Log("in the method.");
        
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "customer")
        {
          Debug.Log("Collision detected!");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be good. Check the following

1. Both the Rigidbodys are set to dynamic.
2. Both the bodies have 2D colliders.
3. They are not colliding already.
4. Both Colliders are not set as trigger.
5. Check the layer collision matrix.(Edit>Project settings>Physics2D)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! After messing around with it for a few hours today I realized that I had the statements hidden in the console, so it was actually working the whole time and I just didn't see it haha.

Answer (score 0):

is the "IsTrigger" checkbox unchecked on your collider component ?
Check if the gameobjects are correctly configured (layers, colliders, tags, your script...) and if you got layers, check the physics settings ;)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! It turns out the Debug statements were just hidden in the console and it was actually working the whole time.